# The question about the proposition $y \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=x \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \Rightarrow f(x,y)=h(x^2+y^2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be $C^1$.

Prove that if  $\ y \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=x \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$ for $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2,$ then $f$ can be written as $f(x,y)= h (x^2+y^2)$.

Here is the proof.

Let $u=x^2+y^2, v=y, f(x,y)=g(u,v)$.

\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}
=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}\Big[g(u,v)\Big]
=
\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}
+\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}=2x \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u},\\
&\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}
=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}\Big[g(u,v)\Big]
=
\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}
+\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}=2y \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u}+ \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}.
\end{align*}

And since $y \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=x \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$ , we get
$x \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}=0$.

Since $x$ is variable, $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}=0$.

Thus we can write $g(u,v)=h(u)=h(x^2+y^2).$

I have two questions.

---

First, why can we let $f(x,y)=g(u,v)$ ?

We let $u=x^2+y^2, v=y$. So $x=\pm \sqrt{u-v^2}$. Thus $x$ is not a function of $(u,v)$, and thus  we cannot write $x$ as $x=x(u,v)$.
What justifies $f(x,y)=g(u,v)$ ?

---

Second, why can we say that the fact that $x \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}=0$ and $x$ is variable implies $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}=0$ ?

Probably we can get $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}=0$ by dividing the both sides of $x \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}=0$, but $x$ can be $0$ and then we cannot devide both sides by $x(=0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, then, by the chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial\theta}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}
=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(-r\sin(\theta))+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(r\cos(\theta))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(-y)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}x=0$$
where $F(r,\theta)=f(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$.
It follows that $F$ does not depend on $\theta$, and therefore it depends just on $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.